# Django Queryset getting a sequence of objects instead of result of a Sum

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to perform a Sum of different rows of the Model according to specific column values, in this case I want to Sum according to a week and an specific car, so for example:

```
Car  Week     Payment
1   2020-W06  $500
1   2020-W06  $300
2   2020-W06  $200
1   2020-W05  $500
```

So I pass to the query the car & the week and it should get the sum of the payments according to those values

I pass Car = 1 and Week = 2020-W06 and Payment Sum = $800

this is my queryset:

```
payed = Pagos.objects.filter(carro_id=1, semana=semana).annotate(total=Sum('pago'))
```

and thi is the result I'm getting:

```
<Pagos: Pagos object (6)>, <Pagos: Pagos object (12)>]
```

I don't understand why I don't get the Sum

> models.py

```py
    class Pagos(models.Model):

        carro = models.ForeignKey(
            Carros, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
        pago = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
        fecha = models.DateField(
            auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
        semana = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        startweek = models.DateField(
            auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
        endweek = models.DateField(
            auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
        renta = models.ForeignKey(
            Renta, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Pagos"

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('pagos')


    class Carros(models.Model):

        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        marca = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        modelo = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        year = models.IntegerField()
        placa = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
        color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        conductor = models.ForeignKey(
            Conductores, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        propietario = models.ForeignKey(Propietarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Vehículos"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('carros')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs annotate adds a filed to each of your model objects, so you get the sum and you can access it like this([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)):

```
payed[0].total
```

If you want to get total value not on just one field you need to use aggregate([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)), it will be like:

```
payed = Pagos.objects.filter(carro_id=1, semana=semana).aggregate(total=Sum('pago'))
print(payed)
# {total: x}
```

About the part you said you want different sums based on fields you can use [conditional clauses in your annotate and aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

Comment: thanks for the guidance, it is working as expected.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!